# Customized coloring for grouped bar graph

Tags: matlab, bar-chart, matlab-figure

```
clear
clc
a = [0.4152 0.4659  0.506   0.5494  0.5676
;0.371  0.4171  0.4649  0.5209  0.5414
;0.2612 0.2681  0.2701  0.2751  0.2811]
b = [0.3976 0.449   0.4951  0.5494  0.5676
;0.342  0.4057  0.4629  0.5701  0.5342
;0.2796 0.2842  0.2911  0.2939  0.2989]
c=[0.3856   0.4397  0.5348  0.5374  0.5562
;0.3352 0.3975  0.4557  0.5087  0.5286
;0.284  0.2928  0.2991  0.301   0.3059]

od = [a,b,c]; % Original Data
d = categorical(["app" "bnn" "orng"]);
d = reordercats(d,{'app' 'bnn' 'orng'});
bar(d,od,'grouped')
```

Basically I want three different colors (and not shades) for three rows of od.
Please help.
I am using MATLAB R2017(a).

Comment: colr = [0  0  0;1 0 0; 0.5 0.5 0.5];

figure
d = categorical(["app" "bnn" "orng"]);
d = reordercats(d,{'app' 'bnn' 'orng'});
colormap(colr);
bar(d,od,'grouped')

This is how I have done it.

Comment: not clear to me what you are trying to get, do you want each group to have a different color?